# Autofac setup with Owin Web API in a AppBuilder.Map block with mixed MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, autofac, owin

I want to move my Web API code into a .Map("/api" inner=>) block so that I can set the following configuration to not affect the MVC parts of my app.

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AuthenticationType))
```

So I tried to put the web api logic in to the .Map but now I broke Autofac and it will no longer resolve dependencies.   here is what I had originally.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    BuildContainer(builder);
    this._container = builder.Build();
    // Middlewares
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(this._container); //should be the first middleware added to IAppBuilder
    app.UseAutofacMvc();     
    // WebApi config
    config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(this._container);

    //MVC
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(this._container)); 
    this.ConfigureAuth(app, _container.Resolve());
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    app.UseAutofacWebApi(config); 
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

Here is what I tried to do but failed with the web api no longer resolving the autofac dependencies.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    BuildContainer(builder);
    this._container = builder.Build();
    // Middlewares
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(this._container); //should be the first middleware added to IAppBuilder
    app.UseAutofacMvc(); 
    //MVC
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(this._container)); 
    this.ConfigureAuth(app, _container.Resolve());

    app.Map(
        "/api",
        inner =>
            {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(this._container);
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            //inner.UseAutofacMiddleware(this._container); //should be the first middleware added to IAppBuilder
            inner.UseAutofacWebApi(config); //Web.API enable lifetime scope created during the OWIN request to extend into WebAPI.
            inner.UseWebApi(config);
        });
}
```

Also If I'm doing anything that looks wrong please let me know.

Comment: I think my problem boiled down to still configuring in Application_Start the GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was WebApiConfig was still being registered in

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{
  GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

Removing this and autofac wired up everything great under the Map.  Strangely having that register there without the map allowed everything to work (perhaps there were other side effects unknown to me).

Final Config I used:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        BuildContainer(builder);
        this._container = builder.Build();
        // OWIN Middlewares
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(this._container); //should be the first middleware added to IAppBuilder
        app.UseAutofacMvc(); // Autofac MVC Integration -- http://alexmg.com/owin-support-for-the-web-api-2-and-mvc-5-integrations-in-autofac/
        //MVC
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(this._container)); //TODO: Still needed with OWIN?
        //app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        this.ConfigureAuth(app, _container.Resolve());
        //WEB API config - Make Web Api urls use the config, avoiding ASP.NET MVC from inheriting the HttpConfig.
        app.Map(
            "/api",
            inner =>
                {
                var config = new HttpConfiguration();
                config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(this._container);
                WebApiConfig.Register(config);
                inner.UseAutofacWebApi(config); //Web.API enable lifetime scope created during the OWIN request to extend into WebAPI.
                inner.UseWebApi(config);
            });
}
```